# Data type for Call Duration field in a MySQL Database

Tags: mysql

I want to record a call duration values in a data base..Which is better , Float or Decimal?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use **DECIMAL UNSIGNED**

```
ALTER TABLE  `tablename` ADD  `call_duration` DECIMAL( 6, 2 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
```

Comment: i think `9999.99` ( max'm) is enough duration

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the granularity you need to store (i.e. parts of seconds) I'd go with either an unsigned smallint (2 bytes) or an unsigned int (4 bytes).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html